# Convert JSON file to Dataframe with defined format

Tags: python, json, dataframe

The JSON file is comprised embedded arrays, like:

`[[[post,post_label], [response,response_label]],[[post,post_label],[response,response_label]],…]`

pd.read_json(url) default reads the file to the Dataframe, which is like:

```
---------------------------------------------------
|      column01        |        column02          |
---------------------------------------------------
|   [post,post_label]  | [response,response_label]|
---------------------------------------------------
|   [post,post_label]  | [response,response_label]|
---------------------------------------------------
```

But, the expected format should be like:

```
---------------------------------------------------
|      column01        |        column02          |
---------------------------------------------------
|       post           |       post_label         |
---------------------------------------------------
|     response         |       response_label     | 
---------------------------------------------------
|       post           |       post_label         |
---------------------------------------------------
|     response         |       response_label     | 
---------------------------------------------------
```

please give some message, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do another one:

```
print(pd.DataFrame(df.values.flatten().tolist(),columns=df.columns))
```

Output will be as desired.